# Pervasive and unixODBC on Ubuntu Server 12.x x64

Tags: ubuntu, unixodbc

I'm trying to setup pervasive client to access a windows server.

1. Extracted Pervasive.SQL-Client-Core-11.30-061.000.x86_64.tar.gz to /usr/local/
2. I installed unixodbc (x64)
3. I ran ./clientpostinstall.sh from /usr/local/psql/etc
4. I linked /usr/local/psql/etc/odbc*.ini to /etc

**/etc/odbcinst.ini**

> [Pervasive]
> Driver=/usr/local/psql/lib/libodbcci.so
> Driver64=/usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so

**/etc/odbc.ini**

> [ODBC Data Sources]
> DALCON = Pervasive ODBC
>
> [DALCON]
> Description=Maestro's DALCON database
> DBQ=DALCON
> Driver=Pervasive
> Servername=DALCON3
> Username=username
> Password=password

**Error:**

> ## isql -v dalcon
>
> [01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so' : file not found
> [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
>
> root@dalcon-www:/usr/local/psql/etc# ls -l /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 psql pvsw 15 sep 13 08:47 /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so -> libodbcci.so.11
> root@dalcon-www:/usr/local/psql/etc# ls -l /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so.11
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 psql pvsw 26 sep 13 08:10 /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so.11 -> libodbcci.so.11.30.051.000
> root@dalcon-www:/usr/local/psql/etc# ls -l /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so.11.30.051.000
> -rwxrwxrwx 1 psql pvsw 662429 jan 18  2013 /usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so.11.30.051.000

Any idea why? I'm running on the root user.

P.S. The formating is bad, dunno why :S

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092840/pervasive-odbc-on-linux-error-01000unixodbcdriver-managercant-open-lib

Comment: root@dalcon-www:/usr/local/psql/etc# su psql
psql@dalcon-www:/usr/local/psql/etc$ cd
psql@dalcon-www:~$ isql -v DALCON
[][unixODBC][Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][Client LNA]A non-recoverable error was returned from the name resolution service.  Contact your system administrator for assistance.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

Answer (score 0):

one must copy psql's .basrsc to root's .bashrc